# Is Google Maps API key needed if the map is simply a local HTML file?

Tags: c#, google-maps, localhost, google-geocoding-api, commercial-application

Our customer needs an application that allows them to input an address and be returned a Google Map HTML file that the user will save to the local file system. The desktop application is written in C# and geocodes the address using the Google Geocoding API. The result is rendered on a Google Maps HTML file that is written to the local machine. My company has purchased a commercial Google API key, however I don't see that we can use it in this scenario, as the domain will be unknown (We won't know where the user chooses to open the file at). The HTML file will not be stored in a publicly available location. Is an API key required? Would we be in any way breaching the TOS?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal issues, not programming.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you only need an API key if you exceed a certain usage limit. Their website would have more information.

Comment: I apologize I should reword my inquiry. When I use our commercial key in the file, I get a response from Google of REQUEST_DENIED. I am assuming this is caused because I am opening the file from a domain not registered in the console. However being how this is a local file and not being served off of a central host, I cannot control what the domain is. Is there a solution to this?